# Can't initialized GraphQl Client in flutter using Get_it

Tags: flutter, graphql, service-locator

I want to implement GraphQL client in my flutter app. For Dependency injection, I use GetIt library. But when I run the app, it says

> '**Invalid argument (Object of type HomeGraphQLService is not
> registered inside GetIt.  Did you forget to pass an instance name?
> (Did you accidentally do  GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt
> sl=GetIt.instance;)): HomeGraphQLService**'

.

It means GraphQL client did not instantiate somehow, although I registered it in my service locator

`Session.dart`

```
abstract class Session {
  String getAccessToken();
}
```

`SessionImpl.dart`

```
class SessionImpl extends Session {
  SharedPreferences sharedPref;

  SessionImpl(SharedPreferences sharedPref) {
    this.sharedPref = sharedPref;
  }

  @override
  String getAccessToken() {
    return sharedPref.getString('access_token') ?? "";
  }

}
```

`GraphQLClientGenerator.dart`

```
class GraphQLClientGenerator {
  Session session;

  GraphQLClientGenerator(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
  }

  GraphQLClient getClient() {
    final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink('https://xxx/graphql');
    final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(getToken: () async => 'Bearer ${_getAccessToken()}');
    final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

    return GraphQLClient(link: link, cache: GraphQLCache(store: InMemoryStore()));
  }

  String _getAccessToken() {
    return session.getAccessToken();
  }
}
```

`HomeRepository.dart`

```
abstract class HomeRepository {
  Future<List<Course>> getAllCourseOf(String className, String groupName);
}
```

`HomeRepositoryImpl.dart`

```
class HomeRepositoryImpl extends HomeRepository {

  HomeGraphQLService homeGraphQLService;
  HomeMapper homeMapper;

  HomeRepositoryImpl(HomeGraphQLService homeGraphQLService, HomeMapper homeMapper) {
    this.homeGraphQLService = homeGraphQLService;
    this.homeMapper = homeMapper;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Course>> getAllCourseOf(String className, String groupName) async {
    final response = await homeGraphQLService.getAllCourseOf(className, groupName);
    return homeMapper.toCourses(response).where((course) => course.isAvailable);
  }

}
```

`HomeGraphQLService.dart`

```
class HomeGraphQLService {
  GraphQLClient graphQLClient;

  HomeGraphQLService(GraphQLClient graphQLClient) {
    this.graphQLClient = graphQLClient;
  }

  Future<SubjectResponse> getAllCourseOf(String className, String groupName) async {
    try {
      final response = await graphQLClient.query(getAllCourseQuery(className, groupName));
      return SubjectResponse.fromJson((response.data));
    }  catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

`GraphQuery.dart`

```
QueryOptions getAllCourseQuery(String className, String groupName) {
  String query = """
    query GetSubject($className: String, $groupName: String) {
      subjects(class: $className, group: $groupName) {
        code
        display
        insights {
          coming_soon
          purchased
        }
      }
    }
    """;

  return QueryOptions(
    document: gql(query),
    variables: <String, dynamic>{
      'className': className,
      'groupName': groupName,
    },
  );
}
```

`ServiceLocator.dart`

```
final serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> initDependencies() async {
  await _initSharedPref();
  _initSession();
  _initGraphQLClient();
  _initGraphQLService();
  _initMapper();
  _initRepository();
}

Future<void> _initSharedPref() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton<SharedPreferences>(sharedPref);
}

void _initSession() {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<Session>(()=>SessionImpl(serviceLocator()));
}

void _initGraphQLClient() {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<GraphQLClient>(() => GraphQLClientGenerator(serviceLocator()).getClient());
}

void _initGraphQLService() {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<HomeGraphQLService>(() => HomeGraphQLService(serviceLocator()));
}

void _initMapper() {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<HomeMapper>(() => HomeMapper());
}

void _initRepository() {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<HomeRepository>(() => HomeRepositoryImpl(serviceLocator(), serviceLocator()));
}
```

`main.dart`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown],
  );
  
  await initDependencies();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Do you access the client from the locator elsewhere in your code before it is instantiated? Meaning do you await the call to initDependencies?

Comment: @Lee3 yes bro. it is called in main() func. Okey I will update the post.

Comment: Try registering all non-lazily.

Comment: @Lee3 same issue bro if I register all of them lazily

Comment: I could not reproduce as the issue is occurring elsewhere in your code, but try my answer. Pretty sure it will resolve the problem.

Comment: I recently made a little app for GraphQL by using [Ferry](https://pub.dev/packages/ferry) and [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get), that app is similar to your app and it is working fine, you can view the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DKX2b0JX-k0s7XnsNYOhJ8-OQhWeY9D3/view?usp=sharing). So I'd recommend you to use those packages.

Answer (score 7):

I cannot say where exactly it is happening because it is elsewhere in your code where you are accessing the `GraphQLService`, but the problem is definitely due to the lazy loading. The object has not been created and loaded by the `locator` before it is being accessed. Try updating `ServiceLocator.dart` to instantiate the classes during registration, like so:

```
void _initSession() {
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton<Session>.(SessionImpl(serviceLocator()));
}

void _initGraphQLClient() {
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton<GraphQLClient>(
    GraphQLClientGenerator(serviceLocator()).getClient());
}

void _initGraphQLService() {
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton<HomeGraphQLService>(
    HomeGraphQLService(serviceLocator()));
}

void _initMapper() {
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton<HomeMapper>(HomeMapper());
}

void _initRepository() {
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton<HomeRepository>(
    HomeRepositoryImpl(serviceLocator(), serviceLocator()));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Let me implement this

Comment: is it possible, the error is in GraphQLClientGenerator class? as I am using InMemoryStore() for storing cache, may be I am doing something wrong here. what's your opinion?

Comment: I don't think so. The error you're seeing should only occur if somewhere in your code, you try to access n object from the `locator` before it has been registered. I don't see that here. A possible cause of this is if your code and/or the packages being used have classes of the same name, and you are inadvertently implementing 2 different ones at each location.